# How do I use the Tkinter 'wait_variable' widget method inside another widget's function to wait for one of two other buttons to be clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter, async-await

I'm relatively new to Tkinter GUI programming in Python. I am trying to implement a behavior in a window containing three buttons using the 'wait_variable' widget method. I have commented my example code below to explain the desired outcome.

```
from tkinter import *

# DEFINE FUNCTIONS

# THIS FUNCTION IS LINKED TO THE MAIN 'EXECUTE' BUTTON
# IT NEEDS TO WAIT FOR THE 'YES' OR 'NO' WIDGET BUTTONS
# THEN PROCEED ACCORDING TO THE VALUE OF THE BUTTON CLICKED
def main_code():
    print("executing main code")
    print("waiting for either 'Yes' or 'No' button to be clicked")
    b_yes.wait_variable(value) # wait for button 'Yes' click
    b_no.wait_variable(value)  # wait for button 'No' click    
    print(str(value) + " button clicked. (1=Yes, 2=No)") # show which button was clicked
    print("continue executing main code") # continue execution 
    print("done")
    return


# BUILD GUI WITH THREE BUTTONS
'''
The GUI has 3 buttons: 'Execute', 'Yes' and 'No'
Desired behaviour:

1. 'Execute' clicked
2. main_code() called
3. main_code() does some stuff
4. main_code() waits for either 'Yes' or 'No' clicked
5. 'Yes' or 'No' clicked
6. main_code() gets value of clicked button
7. main_code() continues execution using button value
8. main_code() returns
'''

root = Tk()
value = IntVar() # 'value' will reflect whether 'Yes' or 'No' button was clicked

b_exec = Button(root, text='Execute', command=main_code)  
b_yes = Button(root, text='Yes', command=lambda: value.set(1))
b_no = Button(root, text='No', command=lambda: value.set(2))

b_exec.pack()
b_yes.pack()
b_no.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the above example code, this happens:

1. click 'Execute' button
2. console displays:
   executing main code
   waiting for either 'Yes' or 'No' button to be clicked
3. click 'Yes' button
   nothing happens
4. click 'Yes' button again
   console displays:
   PY_VAR0 button clicked. (1=Yes, 2=No)
   continue executing main code
   done

The exact same behavior happens if I click the 'No' instead.

Questions:

1. Why does the 'Yes' or 'No' button need to be clicked twice for its method to kick in?
2. How do I get a different integer or string value when one of the buttons is clicked so that it can be used in the rest of the main_code function code?

Any feedback, code examples, actual fix or general hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Regards,
johnnym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `wait_variable()` once:

```py
def main_code():
    print("executing main code")
    print("waiting for either 'Yes' or 'No' button to be clicked")
    root.wait_variable(value) # wait for `value` being updated
    print(str(value.get()) + " button clicked. (1=Yes, 2=No)") # show which button was clicked
    print("continue executing main code") # continue execution 
    print("done")
```